# Displaying an Image HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, blob

I have queried a BLOB my mysql and using the following code I can display the image:

```
<?php 

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['image'];
?>
```

However, my HTML code below will not display. When i take away this php code, it displays. How can I display the image without preventing my HTML from displaying?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file, `image.php` then place the above code in that file.

Then where you want to show your image/html do:

```
<img src="image.php" />
... rest of your html
```

For future reference, the same thing holds true when you are creating Javascript/CSS files via PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you place your php code in a file called image.php, then you can try this

```
<img src="<?php include 'image.php'; ?>" />
```